# How to Convert negative decimal to binary number and and use shift operators in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have this demo program which shows the concept of shift operator in java.But i'm not  clear how this program generates this answer.So please suggest me how to do this.

```
public class Operator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = -10;
        s = s >>2;
        System.out.println("value of i=" + s);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

value of i=-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11110110<sub>2</sub> >> 2 == 11111101<sub>2</sub> == -3<sub>10</sub>

That's a *sign-extended* shift-right operation -- as it shifts right, it doesn't insert zeros at left, but copies the value of the highest bit. The rest of the explanation is about two's complement representation of signed integers.

In general, right-shifting a negative integer by `n` positions will have the effect of dividing by 2<sup>n</sup> and subtracting 1 from that.

Comment: thanks for quick reply,But actually i'm not getting how 11111101=-3,So please give me some example.

Comment: By googling for "two's complement" you'll have that explained in a myriad of nuances, with a cornucopia of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative integers. Thus, `-10` decimal is `1111111111110110` binary.

`>>` is the [sign-extending right shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). This means that if the top bit (that is, the sign bit) is `1` in the first operand, it is also `1` in the result.

Shifting `1111111111110110` by two positions to the right gives `1111111111111101`, which is `-3` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following two lines to your program to clear things up a bit:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-10));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-3));

//Output:
11111111111111111111111111110110
11111111111111111111111111111101
                            --^
```

`>> 2` means shifting the binary represantation of `-10` two positions to the right (yielding `-3`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void decimalToBinaryUsingBitManipulation(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return;
    decimalToBinaryUsingBitManipulation(value >>> 1);
    System.out.print(value & 1);
}
```